# What are the status types for files in the GitHub API v3?

Tags: api, github, github-api

Okay, I'm porting some code that used the GitHub API v2 to v3 and they've changed the way they list files in commits. There's now an array of files, each of which has a status, as opposed to [arrays of 'added', 'modified', and 'removed' files](http://develop.github.com/p/commits.html) like in v2.

Easy, but their examples only show statuses of 'added' & 'modified' and not removed/deleted. I'd assume that it'd be 'removed' like v2, but 'deleted' would be the correct git terminology so I don't want to just assume. The repo I am testing on happens to not have any deleted files, so I have no examples at the moment.

So, which is it 'removed' or 'deleted' in GitHub API v3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is 'removed'. I finally found a commit in one of my repositories where I actually deleted a file and confirmed.

Comment: "changed" is also a possible status. It shows up on [this PR](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/pull/528/files), for example. I'm not sure how it's distinct from "modified".

Comment: I had this same question, and couldn't find anything official, but per [this get-changed-files GitHub Action](https://github.com/jitterbit/get-changed-files/commit/cfe8ad4269ed4d2edb7f4e39682a649f6675bf89#diff-4fab5baaca5c14d2de62d8d2fceef376ddddcc8e9509d86cfa5643f51b89ce3dR5), the possible values are `added`, `modified`, `removed`, `renamed`.

IDK @danvk what you see in your linked PR, I couldn't find `changed` on my quick skim.

Answer (score 1):

The official status is listed in the JSON Schema in the [Commits API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/commits#get-a-commit)

```json
{
  "status": {
    "type": "string",
    "enum": [
      "added",
      "removed",
      "modified",
      "renamed",
      "copied",
      "changed",
      "unchanged"
    ],
    "examples": [
      "added"
    ]
  }
}
```

Tip: the schema is inside the tab next to the examples
[image]